# How to save Captured Video to a folder in asp.net?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, video-capture, bloburls

I have created a sample application in `asp.net` it captures the `Video` from `webcam` and plays it in browser. I want to `save` the `video` in asp.net on save `button click`. Is there any way we can get the `blob url` object on save button click and save the video file to specific `folder`?

`test.aspx` page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {


            let preview = document.getElementById("preview");
            let recording = document.getElementById("recording");
            let startButton = document.getElementById("startButton");
            let stopButton = document.getElementById("stopButton");
            let downloadButton = document.getElementById("downloadButton");
            let logElement = document.getElementById("log");


            let recordingTimeMS = 5000;
            function log(msg) {
                logElement.innerHTML += msg + "\n";
            }
            function wait(delayInMS) {

                return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delayInMS));

            }
            function startRecording(stream, lengthInMS) {
                let recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
                let data = [];

                recorder.ondataavailable = event => data.push(event.data);
                recorder.start();
                log(recorder.state + " for " + (lengthInMS / 1000) + " seconds...");
                $('#startButton').attr('disabled', true);
                $('#stopButton').attr('disabled', false);
                $('#downloadButton').attr('disabled', true);
                $('#<%=btnsaven.ClientID%>').attr('disabled', true);

                let stopped = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    recorder.onstop = resolve;
                    recorder.onerror = event => reject(event.name);
                });

                let recorded = wait(lengthInMS).then(
                    () => recorder.state == "recording" && recorder.stop()

                );

                return Promise.all([
                    stopped,
                    recorded
                ])
                    .then(() => data);
            }
            function stop(stream) {
                stream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());

            }
            startButton.addEventListener("click", function () {

                navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                    video: true,
                    audio: true
                }).then(stream => {
                    preview.srcObject = stream;
                    downloadButton.href = stream;
                    preview.captureStream = preview.captureStream || preview.mozCaptureStream;
                    return new Promise(resolve => preview.onplaying = resolve);
                }).then(() => startRecording(preview.captureStream(), recordingTimeMS))
                    .then(recordedChunks => {
                        // let recordedBlob = new Blob(recordedChunks, { type: "video/mp4" });
                        let recordedBlob = new Blob(recordedChunks, { type: "video/webm" });
                        recording.src = URL.createObjectURL(recordedBlob);
                        downloadButton.href = recording.src;
                        // downloadButton.download = "RecordedVideo.mp4";
                        downloadButton.download = "RecordedVideo.webm";

                        //sms starts here 
                        // generating a random file name
                        var fileName = getFileName('webm');
                        // we need to upload "File" --- not "Blob"
                        var fileObject = new File([recordedBlob], fileName, {
                            type: 'video/webm'
                        });
                        console.log("File Object: "+ fileObject);

                        //sms ends here 

                        $('#startButton').attr('disabled', false);
                        $('#stopButton').attr('disabled', true);
                        $('#downloadButton').attr('disabled', false);
                        $('#<%=btnsaven.ClientID%>').attr('disabled', false);

                        var reader = new FileReader();
                        reader.readAsDataURL(recordedBlob);
                        reader.onloadend = function () {
                            var base64data = reader.result;

                            document.getElementById("<%=hfName.ClientID %>").value = base64data;

                        }


                        stop(preview.srcObject);

                        log("Successfully recorded " + recordedBlob.size + " bytes of " +
                            recordedBlob.type + " media.");


                    })
                    .catch(log);
            }, false); stopButton.addEventListener("click", function () {

                stop(preview.srcObject);
                $('#startButton').attr('disabled', false);
                $('#stopButton').attr('disabled', true);
                $('#downloadButton').attr('disabled', false);
                $('#<%=btnsaven.ClientID%>').attr('disabled', false);

             }, false);

        });



        // this function is used to generate random file name
        function getFileName(fileExtension) {
            var d = new Date();
            var year = d.getUTCFullYear();
            var month = d.getUTCMonth();
            var date = d.getUTCDate();
            return 'RecordDC_' + year + month + date + '-' + getRandomString() + '.' + fileExtension;
        }

        function getRandomString() {
            if (window.crypto && window.crypto.getRandomValues && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') === -1) {
                var a = window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint32Array(3)),
                    token = '';
                for (var i = 0, l = a.length; i < l; i++) {
                    token += a[i].toString(36);
                }
                return token;
            } else {
                return (Math.random() * new Date().getTime()).toString(36).replace(/\./g, '');
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="panel-body">

            <div class="col-md-1">
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">
                <h2>Live Preview</h2>
                <video id="preview" controls width="260" height="150" autoplay muted style="border: solid 2px green; background-color: black"></video>
                <br />
                &nbsp;&nbsp;   &nbsp;&nbsp;
             <div id="startButton" class="button btn btn-success btn-sm">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;Start  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; </div>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;
    
            <div id="stopButton" disabled class="button btn btn-warning btn-sm">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;Stop &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  </div>
                <br />

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h2>Recorded Video</h2>
                <video id="recording" width="260" height="150" controls style="border: solid 2px green"></video>
                <br />

                &nbsp;&nbsp;
              <a id="downloadButton" disabled class="button btn btn-primary btn-sm">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;Download &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</a>

                <asp:HiddenField ID="hfName" runat="server" />
            </div>


            <div class="col-md-12">
                <br />
                <pre id="log"></pre>
            </div>
            <asp:Button ID="btnsaven" runat="server" Text="Save" />
        </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```